# Error when setting the Pusher cluster to 'eu'

Tags: javascript, websocket, pusher

I'm using the [Pusher Javascript library](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js) to create a realtime webapp. Everything works like a charm, however when I set the [`cluster`](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_connect#cluster-smallstringsmall) parameter to `eu` (my users will be connecting from France only), I get an error.

This is the code I use:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('<thisismykey>', {
  encrypted: true,
  authEndpoint: '{{ baseUrl() }}/pusher_auth',
  cluster: 'eu' // This
});
```

And this is the error I get:

```
{
  "type": "WebSocketError",
  "error": {
    "type": "PusherError",
    "data": {
      "code": 4001,
      "message": "Could not find app by key <thisismykey>. Perhaps you're connecting to the wrong cluster."
    }
  }
}
```

Am I allowed to use this parameter? Or is there a thing to do in my Pusher dashboard? The Pusher docs are not quite clear about this.

Comment: A Pusher app exists in a particular cluster. If you get in touch with support, they'll be able to get you an app in the EU cluster.

Comment: Much more clear, thanks! Is this mentioned in the docs? Also, post an anwser so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [@dan_waterworth's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984114/error-when-setting-the-pusher-cluster-to-eu/30185850#comment48091131_29984114):

> A Pusher app exists in a particular cluster. If you get in touch with support, they'll be able to get you an app in the EU cluster.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't help much IMHO.

In my case, I got confused between `PUSHER_KEY` and `PUSHER_APP_ID`.

Hence my code is (in `.erb`):

```
  pusher = new Pusher('<%=ENV['PUSHER_KEY']%>',
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: true,
    authEndpoint: '/notifications/auth'
  )
```